# Change the behavior of the capslock key

Tags: shortcut-keys, capslock

To be honest I'm not sure or what I want is possible but it would be very nice if this can be done.

I changed the behavior of the <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to act like a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. Now it's just an <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key only positioned at an easier to reach place, which is great, but…

It would even be nicer if I could press the Capslock key followed by a second key press. I mean for example: <kbd>Capslock</kbd>(ctrl) → V instead of the normal <kbd>Capslock</kbd>(ctrl) + V.

I guess what I'm looking for is a somewhat similar behavior as the G(go) combinations in Vim or Gmail. Does anyone have an idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know how to arrange the second bit of behaviour. Doing the following should set you up for simply making <kbd>Capslock</kbd> act like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

1. In the dash, search for and launch "Keyboard Layout".
2. Click on "Options" in the  lower right corner.
3. Open "Caps Lock Key Behaviour"
4. Select "Make Caps Lock an additional Control but keep the Caps_Lock keysym"

If  you would prefer to launch this from the terminal, you can do so by running the terminal command `gnome-control-center`. This should bring up a window titled "system settings". You should see several icons, one of which is "Keyboard Layout". Its under the "personal" heading. Once you select it, you can follow the above steps.

Comment: Yes that is how I did that part too. It would be really nice to be able to press it once then follow with an other key instead of holding it down and pressing an other key. Maybe it is just me who thinks that is a good idea, dunno.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. Sorry.

Comment: There is no "Keyboard Layout" in any of my menus, i.e. neither in "System Tools, Administration", nor "System Tools, Preferences". Probably because I use the simple *openwin* as desktop with only some Gnome things (like the *gnome-panel* to get a unbuntu-ish menu at all). Do you happen to know the console command I can bring it up with?

Comment: I've added instructions to do this from the terminal to the original post.

Comment: It seems that 13.10 has changed this. Is there a new way?